# Where did the meteor fall?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock-2

I have found a statue in Legend of Grimrock 2 that says it saw where the meteor fell.

Where did it fall?

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure how much I can say without total spoilers. Are you familiar with the concept of triangulation?

Specifics follow:

> There are two sets of eyes, one left, one right, you need to find both and figure out the exact point at which the two lines from the statues intersect.

Comment: And they're really far from one another.